# Python - implement CUSTOM "lshift" method - but not for bitarray elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, doctest

I have a class which has as parameter list of integer values.
I must implement custom **lshift** method which will do the adding to the list (I must override lshift method for my use case). This is custom lshift method so it does not have anything with **bitarrays** but only working with **integers** in the list (adding it to the list ) and it receives argument **element**. I should do this without **import** of additional python classes. I have defined also tests for this functionality so you can see how result should look like. (I have already implemented custom methods for **add,len and iter** but I suppose this is not relevant)

```
class CustomShift:

    def __init__(self, iterator=None):
        self.iterator = iterator
        if (self.iterator):
            self.iterator = list(dict.fromkeys(self.iterator))

    def __lshift__(self, element):
        """Add an element to the list.

        >>> shiftInstance = CustomShift()
        >>> _ = shiftInstance << 4
        >>> sorted(shiftInstance << 5 << 6 << 4)
        [4, 5, 6]
        """
        if self.iterator is None:
            self.iterator = []
            if element:
                self.iterator.append(element)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    from pprint import pprint
    doctest.testmod()
```

first two tests pass, but third fails!

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, any hint will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `__lshift__` need to return a value - even if it mutates the instance it is working on.  In order for chaining to work the way you expect to, it must return itself.  Since the first `<<` operation doesn't return anything, any subsequent ones will result in the `TypeError` exception you noted.

Second, the `__lshift__` method has a logic error - the element is only appended if the `iterator` argument is `None`.  Thus in the most general use case that you intend, nothing would actually happen.

Finally, in your test case, you wanted to call sort on the object which implies that this object need to provide some kind of iterator (via `__iter__`), otherwise it will simply fail with `TypeError: 'CustomShift' object is not iterable`.  Putting this together, your class will look like so:

```
class CustomShift:

    def __init__(self, iterator=None):
        self.iterator = iterator
        if (self.iterator):
            self.iterator = list(dict.fromkeys(self.iterator))

    def __lshift__(self, element):
        """Add an element to the list.

        >>> shiftInstance = CustomShift()
        >>> _ = shiftInstance << 4
        >>> sorted(shiftInstance << 5 << 6 << 4)
        [4, 5, 6]
        """
        if self.iterator is None:
            self.iterator = []
        if element:
            self.iterator.append(element)
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.iterator)
```

However, the test will still fail, because as it is structured, `shiftInstance` already has a `4` appended which was assigned to `_`.

```
Failed example:
    sorted(shiftInstance << 5 << 6 << 4)
Expected:
    [4, 5, 6]
Got:
    [4, 4, 5, 6]
```

This should however put you towards a direction on how you might want to proceed from what you got.

Comment: can you please explain me in more details for what purposes is this used "_"? what does this line actually do _ = shiftInstance << 4? Thank you

Comment: That `_` is from your test example.  It could be replaced with any other name for that assignment for the return value of the `__lshift__` operation (in your case, it is the instance itself).

Comment: I marked your answer as response. Yes I filtered it additionally and I already had iterable function I just wasn't sure if it related for this or not. I am only confused with that sign from test example "___".  OK so it is needed with any name just for the return value. But how come then for this third test there is no something like "___ = sorted(shiftInstance << 5 << 6 << 4)"... I mean for the third test there is no property for return value. Sorry for being little bit confused (from my side)

Comment: Oh, the assignment is necessary in the doctest to avoid output generated from any return value produced by the executed statement.  In other words, the assignment via the statement `_ = ...` is not strictly necessary in typical code but if it is absent, the doctest will expect to match that output with whatever in the documentation.